# Merging Multiple Dataframes by Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge about 5 Data Frames, each with 2 variables. Each data frame has two variables. The variables are Unique_ID and Year. Each data frame has a different amount of observations.

DF 1

```
Unique ID        Year
1                2010
2                2010
3                2011
```

DF 2

```
Unique ID        Year
3                2010
2                2011
4                2012
```

What is the best way to merge them? I don't mind duplicates. I am actually trying to see how many I have.

Comment: What would be your expected output, just from merging the two dataframes you have posted above? You can add an arbitrary third column that can better showcase this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.partial`:

```
import functools
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
df = functools.partial(pd.merge, on=['Unique_ID', 'Year']) #may have to pass how='outer' or how='left', depending on what you are trying to accomplish
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas.concat:

```
merged = pandas.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5])
```

This will add up all your dataframes